# NSIS: back, next and cancel buttons are disabled in custom page

Tags: nsis

I am trying to create a custom page with NSIS. but when I run the installer, all the buttons are in shadow and not working.

```
Function licensePage

  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0u 100% 12u "Please enter license key"
  ${NSD_CreateText} 0% 20u 100% 12u ""
  Pop $licenseKey

  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40u 100% 12u "Please enter database password"
  ${NSD_CreateText} 0% 60u 100% 12u ""
  Pop $dbPass
  
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

the custom page is so basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to enable next button you have to add these lines

```
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1 ; 1 is the ID of the Next button
EnableWindow $0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Create call.

```
Page custom nsDialogsPage
Page instfiles

Function nsDialogsPage
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
    Pop $0
    
    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
```